# With Chef, how do I run a Rails migration only once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, chef-infra

I'm running a Rails app with three web servers and one database server (an AWS RDS server). I deploy with Chef Solo. Currently I set 'migrate true' in my rails_app recipe, and "rake db:migrate" gets run once on each web server.

This usually isn't a problem when the migrations are short. (The first one succeeds, and the second and third are skipped because the schema_migrations table lists the latest schema version.) But when the migration takes a long time, the second and third web servers attempt to do a migration before the first one is finished. They fail and chef exits unsuccessfully. Note that the migration has succeeded (at least when I've tried it), but the overall deployment of the new version fails. (If I run it again, everything succeeds as the migration has already been run.)

My question is, what's the best / canonical way to ensure that the migration is only run once?

Comment: You could listen to that podcast: http://foodfightshow.org/2013/01/application-deployment.html

Answer (score 0):

May be you can check if the content of the db/migrate.rb file has changed. If so, then conditionally invoke migrate true. If you are using git, you can check

execute "git diff HEAD@{1} HEAD db/migrate"

if any change exists, then use migrate true.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all nodes running the migration, I would use node attributes, so that only one of the converges runs the migration.

In the 'rails_app' recipe your `migrate` property would be;

```
migrate node['rails']['migrate']
```

And then in your node attributes json file for the one node you want to do it;

```
"rails" : { "migrate" : true }
```

and for the other two

```
"rails" : { "migrate" : false }
```

Obviously change the path/name of the attributes as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a leader role for one of your three webservers, and only run db:migrate on that role.

Another option would be deploying your code to the dbserver as well, and running db:migrate right there.